# mpiicpc NO COMMAND Found

Tags: mpi, intel, openmpi, hpc, icc

I want to run a simple MPI Code using Intel Compiler. But I cannot compile the code on Intel C++ icc compiler using mpicc or mpiicpc codes. Kindly please help me run MPI on Intel Compiler on Mac.

I am pretty sure that mpiicpc works, I think there is a problem on whether the appropriate linking files are present?

Comment: `mpiicpc` is from Intel MPI (e.g. not the Intel C++ compiler) package. Make sure the full Intel MPI is installed (e.g. you did not only install the runtime). If the problem persists, please copy/paste your full command line and the full error message.

Comment: Yes, after learning this, I have downloaded openmpi 4.1 and its available on my downloads folder.

Comment: Open MPI != Intel MPI. `mpiicpc` is Intel MPI only, use `mpicxx` with Open MPI (and double check `icpc` is invoked under the hood).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion still I get to see same message:    mpicxx -o HelloMPI HelloMPI.cc
-bash: mpicxx: command not found
:-(

Comment: Sure, you have to build and install Open MPI first and then set its `bin` directory in your `PATH`

Comment: I had installed it on Dowloads folder. Then I moved it to my /user folder by copying and pasting it. Still says it is not working. I also moved .tar file and extracted it using -  tar zxvf openmpi-4.0.1.tar.gz. Still not working :(

Comment: You downloaded a source tarball, now you have to  build and install Open MPI. Or you can install a package (e.g. `sudo apt-get install ...`). Or after all,  installing Intel MPI might be easier for you.